# Lenses shortcuts for Unity-2D

Tags: shortcut-keys, unity-2d

Is it possible to get the same lenses shortcuts for Unity 2D like Super+A and Super+F? I would like to use Unity 2D on some computers, but I miss the shortcuts.

Comment: Answer updated for 12.04. :)

Answer (score 3):

**Update for 12.04**
The shortcuts for activating the various lens are now working and are very much functional in Unity-2D. Unfortunately, this feature has not been backported for 11.10 or older versions. So, if you would like to use this, you have to upgrade to 12.04.